# kpartx in a bash loop

Tags: bash, debian

I'm trying to execute the following lines within a bash script:

```
for i in `ls  /dev/kvm-space/*-backup`
do 
 kpartx -dv "$i"
done
```

But the script doesn't work as expected. The output looks like:

```
failed to stat() /dev/kvm-space/sp-test.disk-backup
failed to stat() /dev/kvm-space/sp-web.disk-backup
failed to stat() /dev/kvm-space/tp-web.disk-backup
```

When I try to execute the kpartx command with a path from the output above manually, kpartx works as expected.

Does anybody has an idea whats going wrong?

Best regards
Thomas

**Edit:**
I'm using Debian Squeeze an the kpartx version 0.4.8 provided via apt.

Comment: This doesn't seem too likely, given your code, but check your `.bashrc` for anything like an alias or function that kpartx would need available to run. Those things aren't available within a script.

Comment: The error message isn't as helpful as it should be; it tells us that the problem occurred when the program used the `stat()` system call, but it does not indicate what the failure was - or the name of the command that encountered the problem.  (You might even report that as a bug to the `kpartx` developers.)  All the usual sorts of explanations (permissions problems, etc) fail to satisfy; if the shell and `ls` managed to generate the file names, there's no reason why `kpartx` could not also access the file, especially since you say it works when run manually.  Are you running as `root` at all?

Comment: Note that the `ls` is redundant; you could simply use `for i in /dev/kvm-space/*-backup` without any (extra) problems.  You haven't tinkered with the IFS variable, have you?

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, your tip without the ls command is great. The loop `for i in /dev/kvm-space/*-backup` works pretty well, but actually this is not really a solution. Furthermore I have no idea why the loop with ls doesn't work.

Comment: @ding280: Are you saying that it works after removing the unnecessary `ls` invocation? FYI, doing anything with the output of `ls` is not recommended (except reading it with your eyeballs).

Comment: @ding280 see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a bunch of reasons why using `ls` non-interactively is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Consider isolating the problem using the below technique:

```
for i in `ls  /dev/kvm-space/*-backup`
do 
    echo kpartx -dv "$i"
done
```

If your output matches what you would have expected Bash to invoke for you, then the problem really lies with kpartx.  I suspect it does.